# ubuntu 14.04 disconnect wired connection when I try to connect broadcom 4311 wifi

Tags: 14.04, broadcom, dell-vostro

I install Ubuntu 14.04 but I don`t have wireless connection because my notebook is a DELL Vostro 1500 with a proprietary broadcom 4311 wireless card. So I read that I have to install the broadcom drivers. Following forum instructions I install b43-fwcutter and firmware-b43-installer and then activate the broadcom driver as a proprietary controller.
Then, I reboot but I had no controller nor wired connection. So I don't know how to recover the wired connection and what I have to do to have wireless connection with the broadcom card. 
Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `bcmwl-kernel-source` actually blacklists the ethernet driver!! It is incorrect for your Broadcom 4311 device. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b44
```

Your ethernet should now be working so that you can install the firmware for your wireless:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After a reboot, both devices should be working.

The 'Additional Drivers' tool will happily offer to install the *wrong* driver for your wireless. Please ignore it.

Comment: Thank you, very much. I will try this afternoon and then I´ll tell you if it´s works!

Comment: I did what you told me and it is working perfectly. Thank you, very much!